# How can we write data to a specific row or column of and excel file using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, xlsx

Suppose that we have this code in MATLAB:

```
data = [1,4,43,21,12];
```

I want to write this to an excel file in row 5. We can use `A5:E5` but the size of my data changes (above `data` is just an example) and I need this data in row 5 of my excel file each time. How we can do this using `xlswrite` or other related functions?

Comment: You may want to look at `xlswrite` function: http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html See the last call form `xlswrite(filename,A,sheet,xlRange)`

Comment: Just specify A5 and no end point

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok opening and closing the entire xls file each time I would load the file into a table:

```
T = readtable('filename');
```

and subsequently access/modify data in the table using curly braces (treat similar to cell array) i.e:

```
D = T{i,j};
```

Finally I would write the table back to an xlsx file:

```
writetable(T,filename);
```

Help on the functions:

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html